# Setting end of tape marker on virtual tape drive (mhvtl)

Tags: linux

Is it possible using a virtual tape drive (mhvtl) to set an end of tape (EOT) marker? I've gone though the `mt` and `mtx` manuals and don't see a way to force a EOT mark on a tape. I'm trying to reproduce an issue that I've seen on a physical tape, only using virtual, and in order to reproduce an EOT mark needs to be present on the tape. Any thoughts?

Comment: Isn't `eot` ASCII `4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a utility with the mhVTL package “*edit_tape*” to resize the virtual media (set/define the EOT).

Comment: It sounds like you've got a possible solution for @Dave. Could you include a link to the documentation of the "edit_tape" package, or better yet, show an example or snippet of using the tool?